# How do I bind a Razor partial to a sub-property of its parent's model?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a form in a Razor page containing loads of fields, all with identical markup.

```
@page "{id:int}"
@model RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies.EditModel

<form method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Movie.Title" class="control-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="Movie.Title" class="form-control" />
      <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="control-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="form-control" />
      <span asp-validation-for="Movie.ReleaseDate" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label asp-for="Movie.Genre" class="control-label"></label>
      <input asp-for="Movie.Genre" class="form-control" />
      <span asp-validation-for="Movie.Genre" class="text-danger"></span>
   </div>
</form>
```

Rather than my page file being stuffed with all this copy/paste I decide to eliminate the code duplication using the feature the ASP documentation says I should be using for this, namely a partial.

So I create a partial

```
@model object

<div class="form-group">
   <label asp-for="@Model" class="control-label"></label>
   <input asp-for="@Model" class="form-control" />
   <span asp-validation-for="@Model" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

...and reference that from my page file using

```
<partial name="_MovieField" for="Movie.Title" />
```

Only problem, nothing works. The `asp-for="@Model"` in the label doesn't resolve the display name for the property so the label is blank, and none of the validation works either.

It seems that if this can be make to work then some kind of specific technique is required to pass a sub-property of a model to a partial in such a way that any tag helpers will still work. Unfortunately the ASP Core documentation doesn't provide any clue as to go about this.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: `asp-for` extracts the name of the specified model property into the rendered HTML. property's name is the bridge between html and model. If you just use `asp-for=@Model`, tag helper will not know which property to bind.

Comment: Binding `@Model` is one of the examples given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#expression-names-and-collections). It doesn't work though.

Comment: The method showed in document is `Templates` and `@Html.EditorFor(xxx)`, Not the partial view. I tried the method and i find that  When you pass object in `templates`, It only pass the value. So it can show validation message normally but It can't  bind property name in `<laber></laber>`..